# How to Use jQuery UI Autocomplete w/ Chrome Speech Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, webkit, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've just recently started utilizing a nifty feature in Chrome that allows you to turn any input field into a speech input a user can dictate into. [More info here](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-speech-input-fields/).

Adding this feature itself is dead-simple in Chrome:

```
<input type="text" x-webkit-speech="x-webkit-speech" /> <!-- you're all set -->
```

I want to implement this feature in my website's main search box, which heavily utilizes jQuery UI's autocomplete widget... However I can't get the autocomplete widget to fire after the dictated text is inserted into the input field.

I've already tried variations of the following:

```
<input id="search-input-box" type="search" x-webkit-speech="x-webkit-speech" onwebkitspeechchange="$('.search-input-box').trigger('autocompleteopen')">
```

How can I trigger the autocomplete "open" event after the speech input change event has occurred?

**UPDATE:** Solved - [jsFiddle of solution here](http://jsfiddle.net/adamb/Tdym3/)

Comment: This is odd. your works just fine with my mic. I start talking and once I am done it opens the auto complete. But the answer below should also solve your problem for anyone who is not getting the autocomplete.

Comment: Perhaps results vary depending on the version of Chrome?

Comment: Might be, I am using Google Chrome version 23.0.1271.64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just bind it to the `webkitspeechchange` event, eg:

```
$('#tags').on('webkitspeechchange', function() {
    $('#tags').trigger('autocompleteopen');
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tdym3/1/)